# How i can give string(html) to ViewModel instead path of html file on zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, dompdf

i have my template just in string  `"<html>..</html>"`
that were responded by an request;

now i want generate an pdf using [DOMpdf](https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule)

```
$pdf = new PdfModel();
    $pdf->setOption('filename', 'monthly-report'); // Triggers PDF download, automatically appends ".pdf"
    $pdf->setOption('paperSize', 'a4'); // Defaults to "8x11"
    $pdf->setOption('paperOrientation', 'landscape'); // Defaults to "portrait"

    // To set view variables
    $pdf->setVariables(array(
      'message' => 'Hello'
    ));
    $pdf->setTemplate("path/to/something.html");

    return $pdf;
```

**instead of `$pdf->setTemplate("path/to/something.html")`** how i can give to $pdf(ViewModel) my string template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need implement your own StringRenderer implementing Zend/View/Renderer/RendererInterface and also extend DOMPDFModule/Mvc/Service/ViewPdfRendererFactory to use your renderer.

This is because, PdfRenderer is hardcoded to use the default ViewManager Renderer and there is no StringRenderer in Zend.

Comment: Probably use different approach, compile php into html string in server and then pass to domPdf load html method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a view model you could return a response:

```
$string = "<h1>hello</h1>";
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setContent($string)->setStatusCode(200);
$response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/html');
return $response;
```

Comment: thanks but isnt that I want, I need to use ViewModel to generate pdf. 'cause my string(template)  comes from an request.

Comment: You should expand a little bit your question in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use different template engine  like mustache or twig ,compile php and then pass to loadHtml method from DOMpdf.